# Guice : Inject mulitple implementation in Single Class constructor

Tags: java, binding, dependency-injection, guice

I have following use case.

```
class ServiceClient {
     Object val;
     @Inject
     public ServiceClient(MyInterface ob){
           this.val = ob.getVal();
     }
}


class UserClass1{
   @Inject
   UserClass1(ServiceClient sc){
   }
}

class UserClass2{
   @Inject
   UserClass2(ServiceClient sc){
   }
}
```

Now while injecting service client in both the user class, I want different implementation of MyInterface injected in ServiceClient constructor class.

How can I achieve this in google Guice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `@Named` annotation to distinguish between different implementations:

```
class UserClass1 {
    @Inject
    UserClass1(@Named("Service1") ServiceClient sc) {
    }
}

class UserClass2 {
    @Inject
    UserClass2(@Named("Service2") ServiceClient sc) {
    }
}

class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(ServiceClient.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("Service1")).toInstance(new ServiceClient(new AA()));
        bind(ServiceClient.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("Service2")).toInstance(new ServiceClient(new AB()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is called the ["robot legs problem"](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#how-do-i-build-two-similar-but-slightly-different-trees-of-objects): Imagine a robot with identical legs but different left and right feet. Using [Private Modules](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/PrivateModule.html), you can privately bind MyInterface twice, and expose your UserClass1 and UserClass2 individually.

```
public class YourModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override public void configure() {
    install(new PrivateModule() {
      @Override public void configure() {
        bind(MyInterface.class).to(MyInterfaceOne.class);
        expose(UserClass1.class);
      }
    });
    install(new PrivateModule() {
      @Override public void configure() {
        bind(MyInterface.class).to(MyInterfaceTwo.class);
        expose(UserClass2.class);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Though this is slightly harder to follow than solutions using `@Named`, it may be more applicable if you want to keep your configuration within your modules instead of expressing the MyInterface varieties in your implementation classes themselves.

Note that using this technique you'll only be able to bind MyInterface within non-conflicting Private Modules, so Guice never has more than one implementation available in any given injection. If you have more than two Private Modules, you may also want to extract them into a named top-level class, which would take the *class to expose* and *implementation to bind* as constructor arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can create 2 different objects of ServiceClient in your Guice Module class with [@Provides](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods) and use [@Named](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations) to inject it into UserClass1 and UserClass2.

In your Guice module:

```
protected void configure(){
  bind(MyInterface.class)
        .annotatedWith(Names.named("A"))
        .to(MyInterfaceImplA.class);  
  bind(MyInterface.class)
        .annotatedWith(Names.named("B"))
        .to(MyInterfaceImplB.class);

}

@Provides 
@Named("serviceClientA")
ServiceClient withInterfaceImplA(@Named("A") MyInterface ob){
   return new ServiceClient(ob);
}

@Provides 
@Named("serviceClientB")
ServiceClient withInterfaceImplB(@Named("B") MyInterface ob){
   return new ServiceClient(ob);
}
```

Then inject it into your UserClass1 and UserClass2

```
class UserClass1{
   @Inject
   UserClass1(@Named("serviceClientB")ServiceClient sc){
   }
}

class UserClass2{
   @Inject
   UserClass2(@Named("serviceClientA") ServiceClient sc){
   }
}
```